# In Matlab, with an English text file, how to load the file and get a matrix as an ASCII encoding result?

Tags: matlab, ascii

Firstly it is a very simple example:

In a text file ('test1.txt'), the content is:

Formally, the

What I want to get is an array with the ASCII encoding result like:

dat_ascii = [70 111 114 109 97 108 108 121 44 32 116 104 101]

In the result, every char is translated to ASCII code, even space and common.

Now I have a text file like 10MB full with English text. I want to read it and translate every char to ASCII code and put them into a matrix (with every 4096 char per line, many lines).

How can I do this in Matlab?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily convert every thing in ASCII with :

`double`, you just cast to double your string.

And to revert it, just do `char`

Example :

```
myStr = 'I have 2 apple.'

myStr =

I have 2 apple.

myASCII = double(myStr)

myASCII =

    73    32   104    97   118   101    32    50    32    97   112   112   108   101    46

myChar = char(myASCII)

myChar =

I have 2 apple.
```

Comment: For line stuff, Just use `reshape` function to get the right number of element per row or column and you get it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to read text file in MATLAB, you need to open the text file and read

`>> filePtr = fopen('test1.txt')`

and then use the file pointer to read the data and convert to ASCII values:

```
>> ASCIIValues = double(textscan(filePtr, '%c')); ASCIIValues{:}
```

Note: Use the appropriate formatting argument when you try to read a text file. In my case, I neglect all whitespaces. For documentation, read http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html